# Apache Bookkeeper delete log

Tags: apache-pulsar, apache-bookkeeper

In Apache bookkeeper how do we delete a log entry in a ledger? If the ledge is immutable and cannot delete entries how does pulsar delete expired messages from bookies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BookKeeper doesn't provide interfaces to delete individual entries in a ledger. It only provides methods to [delete ledgers](http://bookkeeper.apache.org/docs/latest/api/javadoc/org/apache/bookkeeper/client/BookKeeper.html#deleteLedger-long-). Once the ledgers are deleted, bookies will garbage-collect their entries to reclaim disk space in background.

A pulsar topic partition is comprised of multiple ledgers. At any given of time, pulsar broker is writing to one ledger for a partition. After the ledger reaches a given size or after a certain period time, pulsar broker will close the ledger that it is writing and open a new ledger to write. pulsar keeps the list of ledgers as part of the metadata of a topic partition. If all the messages in a ledger have been consumed or expired, the ledger will be deleted by pulsar broker.

Following links are useful to help understand this:

[1] [how a segment-based architecture delivers better performance, scalability, and resilience](https://streaml.io/blog/pulsar-segment-based-architecture/)

[2] [pulsar faq](https://github.com/apache/incubator-pulsar/blob/master/faq.md#since-pulsar-has-configurable-retention-per-namespace-can-i-set-a-forever-value-ie-always-keep-all-data-in-the-namespaces)